# How do I dynamically change the value of [checked] property in ion-checkbox?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

```
<ion-list lines='full'>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
          {{ item.Title}}
      </ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="end"
      (ionChange)="onDataCheckBoxChange(item.Id, $event)" 
      [checked]="item.selected"  
      ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>  
  </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

now on `ngOnInit()` I am returning a an array of item ids i.e. 1,23,4,5,6 etc

Now I want the `[checked]` property to be selected if `item.Id` is in the array of `items ids` I have returned.

So, far I have tried creating another loop on checkbox but it repeats all checkboxes.

How can I can achieve this?

Comment: I can't fully follow, are your items now numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,...) or is it an object? And when is `item.selected` set?

Comment: just array of numbers that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is to map your array of numbers (e.g. `1,2,3,4,5, ...`) to an array of objects (e.g. `[{ id: 1, selected: true }, { id: 2, selected: false}, { id: 2, selected: true }, ...]`) and then also update the selected value in the `onDataCheckBoxChange` function.

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  // this.selectedIds: number[] - contains the initially selected ids
  // numbers: number[] - contains all the numbers e.g. [1,2,3, ...]
  this.data = numbers.map((id: number) => ({ id: id, selected: this.selectedIds.includes(id)});
}

onDataCheckBoxChange(itemId: number, checked: boolean) {
  if ( checked ) {
    this.selectedIds.push(itemId);
  } else {
    this.selectedIds = this.selectedIds.filter((id: number) => id !== itemId);
  }
  this.data.find((item) => item.id === itemId).selected = checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  don't know much about ion, but my approach would be writing a function, that returns true, if the id of the checkbox is in the array, like such:

```
isChecked(itemId) {
    return (checkedIds.find((id) => id === itemId) !== undefined ? true : false);
}
```

and then calling it on the checkbox

Edit: this is assuming your ids are numbers

Edit2: maybe you can use [SelectionModel](https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/overview).

Comment: but in changedetector this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create array and pass the value such as true or false as ion-checkbox only accept true or false.

```
demoArr: any = [
{ id: 1, selected: true },
{ id: 2, selected: false },
{ id: 3, selected: true },];
```

And on the html side do like this you will get your output.

I forked demo example you can check it out here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qzpmhu?file=app/main.ts